# bind with enable_if'd member functions

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, sfinae

I'm getting tripped up on calling bind on an enable_if'd member function. I've worked around it using `if constexpr`, but I'm curious what the solution would be for this issue. The code is the simplest reproducer and not representative of the overarching problem I'm trying to solve. How can I make this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#include <functional>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

template <typename T>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
class test {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

  template <typename U = T>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_copy_constructible<U>::value, void>::type                                                                                                                                                                                     
  foo(const T& v){
      std::cout << "copy constructible";
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

  template <typename U = T>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_copy_constructible<U>::value, void>::type                                                                                                                                                                                     
  foo(const T& v){
      std::cout << "not copy constructible";
  }                                                                                                                                                           

  void foo_bar(const T& v){
      std::cout << "test";
  }
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              


int main(int argn, char** argc){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  test<int> myfoo;           
  myfoo.foo(3); //Works           
  auto func = std::bind(&test<int>::foo_bar, &myfoo, 3);  //Works                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  auto func = std::bind(&test<int>::foo, &myfoo, 3); //Doesn't work                                                                                                                                                                                             

  func();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

}
```

Comment: Why don't use use lambda instead : `auto func = [&myfoo]() { myfoo.foo(3); }`?

Comment: this is a very reduced sample of a low level library. the bind is in code I only have minor control over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `U` is substituted only when the member function template `foo` is actually called, and not when it is used inside of `std::bind()`. This means that when specifying `&test<int>::foo` inside `bind()`, it isn't known which of the two member function templates is going to be actually instantiated since the instantiation of definition will happen when we actually call `foo()`, and so the compiler can't decide which of them you're referring to. This is exactly what `<unresolved overloaded function type>` means in the error that you're getting:

```
no matching function for call to 'bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, test<int>*, int)'
   32 |   auto func2 = std::bind(&test<int>::foo, &myfoo, 3); //Doesn't work
      |                ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You can solve this by either specifying `U` explicitly, like:

`&test<int>::foo<int>`

or by using a **lambda**, like:

`auto func = [&myfoo]() { myfoo.foo(3); };`

---

There is a third way to solve this in C++20 using `requires-clause` as shown below. Note that the below program is well-formed but gcc and msvc incorrectly rejects it. Only clang accepts it which is the correct behavior. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/83oeW6Tx3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#include <functional>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

template <typename T>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
class test {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  void foo(const T& v) requires std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>{
      std::cout << "copy constructible";
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  void foo(const T& v) requires (!std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>) {
      std::cout << "non copy constructible";
  } 
                                                                                                                                                           

  void foo_bar(const T& v){
      std::cout << "test";
  }
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

int main(int argn, char** argc){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  test<int> myfoo;           
  myfoo.foo(3); //Works           
  auto func = std::bind(&test<int>::foo_bar, &myfoo, 3);  //Works                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  auto func2 = std::bind(&test<int>::foo, &myfoo, 3); //works                                                                                                                                                                                           

  func(); 
  func2();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I don't control the bind code, so lambda would have been out, although the proposed fix would be something I could change

Comment: @Steve Can you use C++20? If yes then I have  another solution and can add it. You're welcome :)

Comment: would love to see alternatives. I do have access to c++20

Comment: @Steve I've added a third way of solving it using `requires-clause` in C++20. See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8j9se1z9a). Note that currently only clang accepts the program which is the correct behavior. While gcc and msvc rejects the program and so they have bug. I've submitted the bug for both of those(gcc and msvc as they incorrectly reject the program). I've added the same in my answer.